# RegEx for testing plus or minus sings in numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am trying to use `regex.test` to see if a number has a '+' or '-' at the beginning. What is the best solution?
I've tried this:

```
var regex = RegExp('^[0-9]*$');
var str1 = +384572985;
console.log(regex.test(str1)); //return true

var str2 = "+384572985";
console.log(regex.test(str2)); //return false
```

But I expect both of them to return false!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what might be the best way, however we might be able to do that using an expression similar to:

```
^[+-][0-9]+$
```

[image]

#### Test

```js
const regex = /^[+-][0-9]+$/gm;
const str = `+384572985
-384572985
++384572985
384572985`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/z0Hw6J/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`str1` is not a string. It is getting cast to a string. `+123` evaluates to just `123` before the regex is evaluated due to order of operations. It is like running `/3/.test(1+2)`.